# Show element depending on dropdown's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown that should display different things depending on the selected value:

- When I select "test 1", it should display grid 1
- When I select "test 2", it should not display anything.

Unfortunately, it's displaying the grid also from another dropdown value.

Could you please tell me how to fix it?

Providing my code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/950gacs0/

```
if ($('#combo :selected').text() === "Test 1") {
    alert("test 1 selected");
    $("#grid1").show();
}
else {
    alert("test 2 selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add `.hide()` logic then like this

```
if($('#combo :selected').text() === "Test 1"){
            alert("test 1 selected");
          $("#grid1").show();

}
else {
    alert("test 2 selected");
    $("#grid1").hide();
}
```

because currently selecting test 2 just does nothing but alerting "test 2 selected"

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your click handler to the following:

```
$('#button1Click').on('click', function() { 
  $('#grid1').toggle($('#combo').val() === '1');
});
```

Explanation:

- [`.toggle(display)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)
  will show or hide the set of elements depending on whether its
  parameter resolves to true or false.
- `$('#combo').val() === '1'` will test whether the selected value of your combobox is `1`. This is preferred over testing text/display value.

Comment: @arkr There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/950gacs0/20/. What is confusing?

Comment: hey it doesnt work fine when I add some prefrence in the bottom drop down...can you tell me how to fix it